# Почему мой фон отображается только на одной части сайта

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, body

У меня есть часть кода в css и html:

```css
  * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

::selection {
  background: #f1d2be;
  - /* вот это отображается только на "главном экране". Когда я помещаю его в body,
  то нижняя часть экрана становится розовой: */
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Портфолио</title>
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <nav class="hide">
      <img src="./img/signature.png" class="signature">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-link">
          <a href="#">Работы<i class='bx bx-chevron-down'></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link">
          <a href="#">Обо мне</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link">
          <a href="#">Творчество</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="image-wrap"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [slector ::selection](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_selection.php#) `соответствует той части элемента, которая выбрана пользователем`

Answer (score 1):

Твой код отрабатывает так, как ты его написал.

Из багов, у тебя не закрыт тег со стилями.

**А так же рекомендуется подключать основной файл стилей CSS в самом конце среди всех подключений. Так, как приоритетность воспроизведения браузера идёт сверху - вниз.**